# Ng-show not updating when boolean changes on page with multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I am trying to build an audio player that can be seen across my site. At first it will be hidden, until somebody tries to play an audio file, and then it will pop up at the bottom of the page.

So I have the initial page which has navbar which has it's own controller, then a middle section whose Controller is determined by `ngRoute`, and finally the audio player at the bottom, which is controlled by the `PodcastController`.

When the page loads, the `$scope.showPlayer` variable in the `PodcastController` is initialised to `false`, which hides the player correctly. However, when I later on click on an audio file to play, the `$scope.showPlayer` value gets updated, but it doesn't make the player appear. Very strange.

I have outputted the `$scope.showPlayer` to the console, and it looks like it has been changed to `true`. I've no idea why this isn't updating the ng-show element.

Any ideas?

The ngRoute element in the page is:

```
<div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
```

The audio player at the bottom, which uses angularjs soundmanager2, looks like this:

```
<div class="player-container" ng-show="showPlayer" ng-controller="PodcastController">
  <sound-manager></sound-manager>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" play-music></span> 
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause" pause-music></span>       
  <div class="seekBase" seek-track>
    <div class="seekLoad" ng-style="{width : ( progress + '%' ) }"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" stop-music></span>
<div>
```

One thing that might be relevant is that the general structure of the page when the audio get's clicked would be:

```
<nav ng-controller="SearchController"></nav> ----> Navbar
<div ng-controller="PodcastController"></div> ----> Main Middle Section of Page
<div ng-controller="PodcastController"></div> ----> Player at Bottom of Page
```

ie. There are two elements that are both controlled by the `PodcastController` - not sure if this causes any difficulties... reasonably new to this Angular stuff....

Comment: are you changing the variable from one controller and expecting the changes to reflect in another controller? then that would be scope violation. If you want to share data between two controllers then go for service or factory.

Comment: I was changing it in the PodcastController, which both div would be using so I thought it would be reflected in both places.

Comment: ok, each gets its own scope, so then as I said earlier to share data between two controllers use service.

Comment: that makes sense, that they get their own scope. I've done as you suggested and used a service - it works perfectly. Thanks vinayakj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I solved this problem, was by creating a new controller called PlayerController just for the audio player.

Now, the $scope.showPlayer variable used to toggle the display of the audio player, is then updated via a service by the PodcastController.

ie. when I am on the podcast page, I click a play button and the PodcastController calls a service called, podcast_service, say, and updates the player status there. The PlayerController keeps an eye on the player status in the podcast_service by using the following code:

```
$scope.$watch(podast_service.getPlayerStatus, function() { 
  $scope.showPlayer = podcast_service.getPlayerStatus()
});
```

This way any time the podcast_service gets the player status changed, the PlayerController notices, and hides/shows the player. All very neat.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the two elements that both use the PodcastController in a common element and put the controller on that element. Like this:

```
<div ng-controller="PodcastController">
    <div></div> ----> Main Middle Section of Page
    <div></div> ----> Player at Bottom of Page
</div>
```

Comment: That stops the ngRoute from working - so that is a non-runner. Why would this work anyway?